# Skewed plane partition with only row fillings reversed

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, partitions, young-tableaux

The number of plane partitions in a bounded box is well-studied and dates back to MacMahon, at the start of this paper by [Sam Hopkins and Tri Lai](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.05381), p9, they summarized current results on the enumerations of several classes of plane partitions, especially the enumeration of skewed plane partitions of any shape $\lambda/\mu$ whose largest entry is bounded by some $m$, for any Young diagram $\mu$ contained in $\lambda$.

My question: is there a similar enumeration for the skewed plane partition of shape $\lambda/\mu$ with only row fillings reversed, i.e. weakly increase in the row fillings but weakly decrease in the column fillings?

Using LGV lemma is one possible approach as in [this paper](https://people.brandeis.edu/%7Egessel/homepage/papers/pp.pdf), we can reflect the shape horizontally and get a shape which weakly decreases in both directions, but it's no longer a skew shape, machinery in the paper doesn't apply directly.

Unlike other nice symmetry classes, based on my computation of a few simple cases, this enumeration formula may not have a nice product formula consisting of only linear terms but rather has a higher order irreducible polynomial and other linear terms.I haven't found any reference to this kind of plane partition, any reference will be appreciated.